# Do Iran or UK have laws regarding unauthorized negotiations with foreign powers?

Tags: united-kingdom, iran

Do Iran or United Kingdom have laws prohibiting their citizens to partake in diplomatic matters concerning the state?

For example. Sweden has such a law in [brottsbalken 19 kap 4§](https://lagen.nu/1962:700#K19P4S1),
translated as

> Swedish citizens who, without the permission of the government or the
> government authorized, allow themselves to be used as representatives
> of foreign powers in diplomatic matters concerning the state, as well
> as anyone who, in the alleged capacity of competent representative,
> engages in negotiations on such matters with someone who enters the
> interest of a foreign power, is sentenced for arbitrariness in
> negotiations with a foreign power to imprisonment for a maximum of two
> years or, if the kingdom was at war, a maximum of four years.

Comment: The US version is called the Logan Act.  I tried searching for "Logan Act UK equivalent", but found only a [petition](https://petition.parliament.uk/archived/petitions/255858) from some people who thought the UK *ought* to have one, and a [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-US-Logan-Act-in-UK-law) suggesting it would likely be charged as fraud or treason instead.

Comment: FWIW, the translation rendering of "arbitrariness in negotiations with a foreign power" is inapt and not colloquial, as does "who enters the interest of a foreign power." A description calling this "unauthorized negotiations with foreign powers" night be a better translation.

Comment: Priti Patel broke ministerial rules when she held unauthorised meetings with Israeli government figures, and was forced to resign, but there was no suggestion that she broke any law. https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/nov/08/priti-patel-forced-to-resign-over-unofficial-meetings-with-israelis